# Filter date on SQL visual studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio

i have a problem with a filter on View in visual studio
I have a column with a value DATE and i would like to filter a row on my table with date today - 180 days.
a column date is formatted "27/01/2020  00:00:00"

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have find a solution. DataDoc >= DATEADD(MM, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))